Ubuntu + dependencies error
I have the following dependency problem. How can I solve it?
Thank you
The following packages have unfulfilled dependencies:
  zookeeper-1-2-2-0-46-server : Depends: zookeeper (= 3.8.3.1.2.2.0-46) but 3.8.4.1.2.2.0-138 is going to be installed
E: Problems could not be corrected, you have retained broken packages.

EDIT:
Ubuntu 22.04
I'm trying to install zookeeper server.
apt install zookeeper-1-2-2-0-46-server


Please [edit] your question and give us some context so we can understand. First, which version of Ubuntu is this? Then, what command did you run to get this error? What package are you trying to install? Have you run apt update?

Yes, I run "apt update"
Trying to install: zookeeper-1-2-2-0-46-server

what about sudo apt install -f

Don't use apt install -f in my personal opinion this causes more issues than fixes.  What does apt install zookeeper produce?  See: apt-get: reasons for “…but it is not going to be installed” - Duplicate

Update your package lists:
sudo apt update

installation of the required zookeeper version:
sudo apt install zookeeper=3.8.3.1.2.2.0-46


Thanks!! it worked
